# Micropython _thread stop thread

Tags: multithreading, sockets, esp32, micropython

I'm building an LED lamp using an ESP32 with micropython. It's controlled from  software developed with customtkinter via WIFI through sockets. I'm using _thread library to manage the LED animations while still listening for new sockets connections in order to stop or change the running animation.
For some reason, the rainbow animation runs, changes and stops flawlessly, but when I run the 'Fill and Empty lights' (which re functions fill, empty both run by upDown() function) it misbehaves when i change the speed of the animation even though looks like I'm able to stop it at least for the first time using showColor() function passing 'black' as color parameter. This is my first time making a project with an ESP32 and with threading too.
Any help would be so appreciated.

```
# ESP32 LED STRIP

# Import Dependencies
from machine import Pin
from neopixel import NeoPixel
from time import sleep
import socket
import _thread

# Create Socket Server
try:
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8266))
    server_socket.listen(5)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)



# Led Strip Config
LEDS = 30
pixels = NeoPixel(Pin(21), LEDS)

# Define colors
colors = {'black' : (0, 0, 0),
          'red' : (255,0,0),
          'green' : (0, 255, 0),
          'blue' : (0, 0, 255),
          'white' : (255, 255, 255),
          'yellow' : (170, 100, 0),
          'cian' : (0, 255, 255),
          'magenta' : (255, 0, 255),
          'pink' : (125, 25, 55),
          'violet' : (136, 0, 255),
          'orange' : (211, 84, 0)
          }

# Create list Rainbow colors
rainbow_colors = []

for i in colors:
    if colors[i] != colors['black'] and colors[i] != colors['white']:
        rainbow_colors.append(colors[i])


#For reference:
#animations = ('Solid', 'Up', 'Down', 'UpDown', 'Run', 'Back', Rainbow)



# Define Patterns
def showColor(color):
    for led in range(LEDS):
        pixels[led] = colors[color]
    pixels.write()
    

def fill(color, seg):
    print('start fill')
    for led in range(LEDS):
        pixels[led] = colors[color]
        pixels.write()
        sleep(seg)
        if not should_run:
            break
        
    

def empty(color, seg):
    print('start empty')
    for led in range(LEDS - 1, -1, -1):
        pixels[led] = colors[color]
        pixels.write()
        sleep(seg)
        if not should_run:
            break



def upDown(color1, color2, seg):
    print('start upDown')
    fill(color1, seg)
    sleep(0.1)
    empty(color2, seg)
    sleep(1)
    sleep(0.1)



def run(color, seg):
    for led in range(LEDS):
        pixels[led-1] = colors['black']
        pixels[led] = colors[color]
        pixels.write()
        sleep(seg)
    pixels[led] = colors['black']
    pixels.write()


def back(color, seg):
    for led in range(LEDS - 1, -1, -1):
        if led < LEDS - 1:
            pixels[led+1] = colors['black']
        pixels[led] = colors[color]
        pixels.write()
        sleep(seg)
    pixels[led] = colors['black']
    pixels.write()

def rainbow(offset): #:D
    print('Start Rainbow')
    num_colors = len(rainbow_colors)
    spacing = LEDS // num_colors
    
    for i in range(LEDS):
        group_index = (i - offset) // spacing
        
        color_index = group_index % num_colors
        
        pixels[i] = rainbow_colors[color_index]
    pixels.write()
    
# Define Run Animes
def run_upDown(color1, color2, speed):
    while should_run:
        fill(color1, speed)
        sleep(0.1)
        empty(color2, speed)
        sleep(0.1)
        if not should_run:
            break
        '''
        print('start fill')
        for led in range(LEDS):
            pixels[led] = colors[color1]
            pixels.write()
            sleep(speed)
            if not should_run:
                break
        print('start empty')
        for led in range(LEDS - 1, -1, -1):
            pixels[led] = colors[color2]
            pixels.write()
            sleep(speed)
            if not should_run:
                break
        if not should_run:
            break
            '''
    

def run_rainbow(speed):
    offset = 0
    while should_run:
        rainbow(offset)
        offset += 1
        sleep(speed)
    return


# Main Loop Wait for connections
while True:
    print('Waiting for you...')
    try:
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        print(client_address, 'connected')
        
        data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
        print(data)
        
        color1, color2, anime, speed = data.strip().split(',')
        print(color1, color2, anime, speed)
        
        speed = float(speed)
        speed = round(speed, 2)
        print(speed)
         
        should_run = False
        sleep(1)
        
        if anime == 'Solid':
            showColor(color1)
        
        elif anime == 'Up':
            fill(color1, speed)
        
        elif anime == 'Down':
            empty(color1, speed)
        
        elif anime == 'UpDown':
            should_run = True
            _thread.start_new_thread(run_upDown, (color1, color2, speed))
        
        elif anime == 'Run':
            run(color1, speed)
        
        elif anime == 'Back':
            back(color1, speed)
            
        elif anime == 'Rainbow':
            should_run = True
            _thread.start_new_thread(run_rainbow, (speed,))
        
        
        client_socket.close()
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I'm using a boolean variable called 'should_run' in order to break the loops that run the animations by changing its value from False to True. This seemed to work fine with Rainbow but with upDown() it just keeps running the last process/loop and gets mixed with the new one.

UPDATE: run_rainbow function also misbehaving when changing speed from short pause to long pause, especially after a few changes.

Comment: The problem is that you run multiple threads that access the same shared resource. This results in the misbehaving. To solve this, you could put all code that accesses the LED in a single thread, or you could use a mutex. I would recommend to learn something more about multithreading and the risks/difficulties that come with it and how to solve them, since this are common problems and there is plenty of information/explanation available eg [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#Single-threaded_vs_multithreaded_programs) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety)